# Refresh Data in SwiftUI View pulled from HTTP Request

Tags: rest, swiftui, httprequest

I've been looking for a solution to this problem but none of the ones I've found seem to fix my specific situation. Hopefully, with these details, someone can help me out. I'm new to Swift so bear with me. I'm working with a REST Api and HTTP Request from our help desk ticket system. I'm trying to find a way to refresh the data automatically when something changes and also have a way to manually refresh i.e. a pull down or actual refresh button. If I can figure this out for the two scenarios below, I think I can apply it to the rest of my scenarios.

Scenario #1 - I submit a new note for a ticket but the detail view doesn't change to reflect that new note. I have to go back and reopen the view to see the change.

[image]

**Fetch Ticket Details**

```
struct TicketDetails: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var type: String
    var location: Location
    var detail: String
    var notes: [Notes]
    var statustype: StatusType
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let locationName: String
}

struct Notes: Codable {
    var prettyUpdatedString: String?
    var mobileNoteText: String?
}

struct StatusType: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var statusTypeName: String
}

class FetchTick: ObservableObject {
    func getTicket(id: Int, userApi: String, completion: @escaping (TicketDetails) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "URL FOR TICKET DATA") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            let ticket = try! JSONDecoder().decode(TicketDetails.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(ticket)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

**Create New Note on Ticket**

```
class CreateTicketNote: ObservableObject {
    func CreateNoteAction(ticketId: Int, userApi: String, techNote: String) {
        
        let ticketUrl = URL(string:
            "URLFORTICKET")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: ticketUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        
        let json: [String: Any] = [
            "noteText": techNote,
            "jobticket": [
                "id": ticketId,
                "type": "Ticket"
                ]
        ]
        
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)

        
        URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: data) { (responseData, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error making POST request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            if let responseCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, let responseData = responseData {
                guard responseCode == 200 else {
                    print("Invalid response code: \(responseCode)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let responseJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .allowFragments) {
                    print("Response JSON data = \(responseJSONData)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Detail View**

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var ticketStatusAction = TicketStatusAction()
    @ObservedObject var createTicketNote = CreateTicketNote()
    @State var ticket: [TicketDetails] = []
    @State private var showingNoteAlert = false
    @State private var showingOpenAlert = false
    @State private var showingPendingAlert = false
    @State private var showingDepotAlert = false
    @State private var showingCloseAlert = false
    @State private var note: String = ""

    var id: Int
    var displayClient: String
    @Binding var userApi: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                           Text(self.ticket.first?.location.locationName ?? "")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding()

                           }
                
                
                Text("\(displayClient) - \(id)")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(size:20))
                    .padding()

                Divider()
                
                Text("Status")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                    Text(self.ticket.first?.statustype.statusTypeName ?? "")
                    .padding()
                }
                
                Text("Details")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
                
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                    Text(clearMarkdown(on:self.ticket.first?.detail ?? ""))
                               .padding()
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                           }
                Divider()

                Text("Most Recent Note")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
                
                if !ticket.isEmpty {
                    Text(clearMarkdown(on: self.ticket.first?.notes.first?.prettyUpdatedString ?? ""))
                           .padding()
                    Text(clearMarkdown(on: self.ticket.first?.notes.first?.mobileNoteText ?? ""))
                           .padding()
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                       }
            }
            .onAppear {
                FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                    self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                }}
            
            Divider()

               Section(header: Text("Create New Note")
                   .fontWeight(.bold)
                   .padding()
                   .padding(10)
                   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)) {
                       
                   TextField("Enter your note", text: $note)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 350)
                    .padding(15)

                   
                   Button(action: {
                       self.showingNoteAlert = true
                   }) {
                       Text("Submit Note")
                       .frame(width: 300)
                       .padding(15)
                       .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                       .background(Color.orange)
                       .cornerRadius(5)
                   }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()
                   ).actionSheet(isPresented:self.$showingNoteAlert) {
                       ActionSheet(
                           title: Text("Are you sure you want to add this note to \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                           message: Text("\(self.note)"),
                           buttons: [
                        .default(Text("Submit"))
                            {
                                self.createTicketNote.CreateNoteAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, techNote: self.note);
                                self.note = ""
                            },
                        .cancel(){
                            self.note = ""
                            }])
                   }
               }
            
            Divider()

            Section(header: Text("Change Ticket Status")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding()
                .padding(10)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)) {
                                    
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingOpenAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Open")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingOpenAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want change \(displayClient)'s ticket to Open?"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Open"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 1)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingPendingAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Pending")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingPendingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to set \(displayClient)'s ticket to Pending?"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Pending"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 2)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDepotAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Depot")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingDepotAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to depot \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                        primaryButton: .default(Text("Depot"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi,
 desiredStatus: 6)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingCloseAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Close")
                    .frame(width: 300)
                    .padding(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()).alert(isPresented:self.$showingCloseAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure you want to close \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Close"))
                            {
                                self.ticketStatusAction.TicketAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, desiredStatus: 3)
                            },
                        secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Scenario #2 - I'm viewing a list of tickets and want to make sure no additional tickets have opened. I would like to pull to refresh the list and show any new tickets.

**Fet Tickets By Location**

```
struct TicksByLocation: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var type: String
    public var displayClient: String
    public var shortDetail: String
}

class FetchTicksByLocation: ObservableObject {
    
    func getTicksByLocation(ticketLocation: String, userApi: String, completion: @escaping (([TicksByLocation]) -> ())){
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "URLFORTICKETS") else {
        return
    }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let tickData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([TicksByLocation].self, from: tickData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(decodedData)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Show Tickets By Location**

```
struct ShowLocationView: View {
    @Binding var ticketLocation: String
    @Binding var userApi: String
    @Binding var tickets: [TicksByLocation]
    @State var openTickets: [TicksByStatusAndLocation] = []
    @State var green = Color.green
    @State var yellow = Color.yellow
    @State var blue = Color.blue
    @State var purple = Color.purple



    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(tickets) { tick in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Text("\(tick.id)")
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                    
                    Text(tick.displayClient)

                    Text(tick.shortDetail)
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(
                        id: tick.id,
                        displayClient: tick.displayClient,
                        userApi: self.$userApi
                    )) {
                       Text("See Details")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

                        }
                    Divider()
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(
                Text("\(ticketLocation) - All (\(tickets.count))"),
                displayMode: .inline
            )
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                Text("Filter")
                .contextMenu {
                 NavigationLink(
                    destination: ShowLocationAndStatusView(
                        ticketLocation: $ticketLocation,
                        userApi: $userApi,
                        status: "Open",
                        color: green
                        )
                    ) {
                 Text("Open")
                   }
                    
                NavigationLink(
                   destination: ShowLocationAndStatusView(
                       ticketLocation: $ticketLocation,
                       userApi: $userApi,
                       status: "Pending",
                       color: yellow
                       )
                   ) {
                Text("Pending")
                  }
                    
                NavigationLink(
                   destination: ShowLocationAndStatusView(
                       ticketLocation: $ticketLocation,
                       userApi: $userApi,
                       status: "Depot",
                       color: blue
                       )
                   ) {
                Text("Depot")
                  }
                    
                NavigationLink(
                   destination: ShowLocationAndStatusView(
                       ticketLocation: $ticketLocation,
                       userApi: $userApi,
                       status: "Agi",
                       color: purple
                       )
                   ) {
                Text("Agi")
                  }
                    
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #1

```
Section(header: Text("Create New Note")
                   .fontWeight(.bold)
                   .padding()
                   .padding(10)
                   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)) {
                       
                   TextField("Enter your note", text: $note)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(width: 350)
                    .padding(15)

                   
                   Button(action: {
                       self.showingNoteAlert = true
                   }) {
                       Text("Submit Note")
                       .frame(width: 300)
                       .padding(15)
                       .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                       .background(Color.orange)
                       .cornerRadius(5)
                   }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()
                   ).actionSheet(isPresented:self.$showingNoteAlert) {
                       ActionSheet(
                           title: Text("Are you sure you want to add this note to \(displayClient)'s ticket?"),
                           message: Text("\(self.note)"),
                           buttons: [
                        .default(Text("Submit"))
                            {
                                self.createTicketNote.CreateNoteAction(ticketId: self.id, userApi: self.userApi, techNote: self.note);
                                self.note = "";
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                                    FetchTick().getTicket(id: self.id, userApi: self.userApi) { (ticketDetails) in
                                        self.ticket = [ticketDetails]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        .cancel(){
                            self.note = ""
                            }])
                   }
               }
```

Solution #2

Using https://github.com/phuhuynh2411/SwiftUI-PullToRefresh

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ShowSelectedStatus: View {
    @State private var isShowing = false
    @Binding var userApi: String
    @Binding var tickets: [TicksByStatus]
    var ticketStatus: String
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(tickets) { tick in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    
                    Text(tick.displayClient)
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(self.color)
                    .cornerRadius(5)

                    Text(tick.shortDetail)
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(
                        id: tick.id,
                        displayClient: tick.displayClient,
                        userApi: self.$userApi
                    )) {
                       Text("See Details")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

                        }
                    Divider()
                    }
            }
            .pullToRefresh(isShowing: $isShowing) {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    self.isShowing = false
                }
                FetchTicksByStatus().getTicksByStatus(
                    ticketStatus: self.ticketStatus,
                    userApi: self.userApi
                 ) {
                    (ticks) in self.tickets = ticks
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(
                Text("\(ticketStatus) (\(tickets.count))"),
                displayMode: .inline
            )
        }
    }
}
```